# when i write a GET orPOST method with params...then call it,if some params isn't filled in,the params will be set as null,right?

Tags: java, http, rest, jersey

when i write a GET or PUT method with params...then call it,if some params don't fill in,the params will be set as null,right?
such as

```
@POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Override
    public String create( @QueryParam("meg")String megString, @QueryParam("name")String nameString) {
       TestUser testUser=new TestUser();
       testUser.setMeg(megString);
       testUser.setName(nameString);
       em.persist(testUser);
       em.flush();
       return testUser.getId().toString();

    }
```

then i post the url www.XXX.com/create?meg="asdas"
the param name is not filled in ,will the value be null when it called?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if some params don't fill in,the params will be set as null,right?`
It depends, on the default value of Input Parameters. In your case it will not set `null`, Because your input parameter (`name`) is `String` so the default value of `String is empty or "" but not null`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Jersey sets the value of the string parameter to null if it is not present in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Right, unless the type is an object variant of a primitive type in which case it would be the default value of that primitive type (e.g. an Integer parameter value would be 0).